# Laravel with Postfix

Tags: laravel, email, postfix-mta

I was using gsuite to send mail from laravel, config on .env was:

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
 MAIL_PORT=465
 MAIL_USERNAME=account@gmail.com
 MAIL_PASSWORD=password123
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

It is working ok, but now i installed postfix as a send-only to send newsletters and tested via command line like this:

```
echo "Teste message" | mail -s "Title Message" any@email.com
```

And it worked ok, but i cant figure on how to use it on laravel, what should be the configuration? I tried this:

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=localhost
 MAIL_PORT=25
 MAIL_USERNAME=null
 MAIL_PASSWORD=null
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

But it return:

```
Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""
```

Comment: Solved it with: MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail